# multiple scope rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

```
class Anketum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user 

  class << self
    def search(params)
      self.scope :h, :conditions => {:height => params[:height]}
      #scope :w, :conditions => {:width => params[:width]}
      self.h if params[:height]
    end

  end
end
```

I need to create multiple scope depend on params[:xxx] present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your code sample, you're way over-engineering this:

```
# app/models/anketum.rb
class Anketum < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# app/controller/some_controller.rb
def search
  @results = Anketum.scoped
  [:width, :height, :any, :other, :searchable, :attribute].each do |key|
    @results.where(key => params[key]) if params[key].present?
  end
end
```

Your models should never access the `params` hash, by the way.

Comment: where cause doesn't work... strange `SELECT "anketa".* FROM "anketa"`

Comment: Is your db table also called "anketa"? If not, you have something very wrong with your setup.

Comment: Which Rails version are you on? I assumed 3 since you're using `scope` instead of `named_scope`.

Comment: Rails 3. You propose nifty solution, but I think I can't escape way of complicated sql query in my task

Comment: You're using AR wrong; this is a common problem. You're not doing a complicated query — you're breaking separation of concerns and overengineering. Sorry to be dick-ish, but Google it.